# Sql query to select data from the day before at 4:15:01 pm to today at 4:15:00 pm

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, ssis

I'm building a SSIS package where I need to get data from the day before at 4:15:01 pm to today's date at 4:15:00 pm, but so far the only query that I know is how to get the day before. I am not sure how to also add hour, minute, and second to the same query. Can someone please show me how to add the hour, minute, and second to this sql query? 
Below is the query I have so far.

```
SELECT Posted_Date, Total_Payment FROM   
Table1
WHERE Posted_Date >= dateadd(day, datediff(day, 1, Getdate()), 0)
and Posted_date < dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, getdate()), 0)
order by posted_date
```

Comment: [You should always reference an object's schema](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/11/bad-habits-to-kick-avoiding-the-schema-prefix.aspx) and also [get in the habit of terminating statements with semi-colons](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/09/03/ladies-and-gentlemen-start-your-semi-colons.aspx).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Be very careful about precision here - saying you want things from 4:15:01 PM yesterday, means that at some point you could possibly lose data (e.g. 4:15:00.500 PM). Much better to use an open-ended range, and I typically like to calculate that boundary outside of the query:

```
DECLARE @today DATETIME, @today_at_1615 DATETIME;

SELECT @today = DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()), 0), 
       @today_at_1615 = DATEADD(MINUTE, 16.25*60, @today);

SELECT Posted_Date, Total_Payment
FROM dbo.Table1
WHERE Posted_Date > DATEADD(DAY, -1, @today_at_1615)
  AND Posted_Date <= @today_at_1615
ORDER BY Posted_date;
```

You should also avoid using `DATEDIFF` in queries like this - there is [a cardinality estimation bug](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2481274) that can [really affect the performance of your query](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2013/09/t-sql-queries/datediff-bug). I don't believe the bug affects SQL Server 2005, but if you wanted to be ultra-safe you could change it to the slightly more expensive:

```
SELECT @today = CONVERT(CHAR(8), GETDATE(), 112),
```

And in either case, you should mark this code with some kind of flag, so that when you do get onto SQL Server 2008 or later, you can update it to use the much more optimal:

```
SELECT @today = CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()),
```

## SSIS things

I created an SSIS package with an `Execute SQL Task` that created my table and populated it with data which was then used by a `Data Flow Task`

[image]

### Execute SQL Task

I created an Execute SQL Task, connected to an OLE DB Connection Manager and used the following direct input.

```
-- This script sets up a table for consumption by the DFT
IF EXISTS
(
    SELECT * FROM sys.tables AS T WHERE T.name = 'Table1' AND T.schema_id = SCHEMA_ID('dbo')
)
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE dbo.Table1;
END;
CREATE table dbo.Table1
(
    Posted_Date datetime NOT NULL
,   Total_Payment int NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO 
    dbo.Table1
(
    Posted_Date
,   Total_Payment
)
SELECT
    DATEADD(minute, D.rn, DATEADD(d, -1, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)) AS Posted_Date
,   D.rn
FROM
(
    -- 2 days worth of data
    SELECT TOP (60*24*2)
        DI.rn
    FROM
        (
            SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS rn
            FROM sys.all_columns AS AC
        ) DI
) D;
```

Right click on the Execute SQL Task and execute it. This ensures the table is created so that we can work with it in the next step.

### Data Flow Task

I created a `Data Flow Task` and set the `DelayValidation` property to True since my connection manager is pointed at tempdb. This is likely not needed in the real world.

I added an OLE DB Source component and configured it to use the first query

[image]

I then added a Derived Column to allow me to attach a data viewer to the flow and fired the package off. You can observe that the last value streaming through is as expected.

[image]

Comment: I tried your query and this is the error I'm getting in SSIS, how do I fix this error? 

Error at Data Flow Task [OLE DB Source [11]]: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80040E14.
Native Client 11.0"  Hresult: 0x80040E14  Description: "Must declare the scalar variable "@today_at_1615".".
An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0"  Hresult: 0x80040E14  Description: "Cannot assign a default value to a local variable.".

Comment: @Lily what version are you using?

Comment: Visual Studio 2010, framework 4, and Microsoft Sql server 2008 r2

Comment: I'm sorry, this is one of our so many servers. This specific server is Microsoft server 2005 r2,  not 2008

Comment: Just 2005. The R2 naming stupidity, with regards to SQL Server, is only valid for SQL Server 2008.

Comment: I got it to work with sql task from billinkc and Aaron's query. Thank you so much. I'm starting to learn about SSIS and sql, and I sure will keep in mind all of your comments Aaron. I want to thank everyone for trying to help me too.

Comment: One of the problems was `SELECT @today = CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()), instead I changed it to SELECT @today = CONVERT(DATETIME, GETDATE()),` and it worked.

Comment: @Lily Hmmm, that actually shouldn't work, except at exactly midnight. Converting GETDATE() to DATETIME does not trim the time like converting GETDATE() to DATE would. I've updated the answer to use a 2005-friendly equivalent.

Comment: You were right, I didn't see 12/05/2013 data before. Thank you Aaron so much and for having patience with me. YOU ARE GREAT!!!

Answer (score 0):

I'd think this would work similarly.

```
DECLARE @today DATETIME, @today_at_1615 DATETIME;
SELECT @today = CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()), 
    @today_at_1615 = DATEADD(MINUTE, 16.25*60, @today);

SELECT Posted_Date, Total_Payment
FROM dbo.Table1
WHERE Posted_Date between DATEADD(DAY, -1, @today_at_1615) AND @today_at_1615
ORDER BY Posted_date
```

Would've made a comment about using BETWEEN but I don't have the reps for it.  Is there a reason for not using the between clause?

Comment: There are MANY reasons to not use BETWEEN. For one, on subsequent days you'll double-count data from exactly 4:15 PM. I assume you'll only want to count that data on one day (and the wording of the question sounds like today). Please read: https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common.aspx

Comment: Even if BETWEEN were valid (let's say my query that you copied used >= AND <=), what about this answer would be different?

Comment: Aside from what you've noted in your blog entry, in the long run, your code would be handle changes to the database better.

Answer (score -6):

Another way of asking the same question: Show me the data that would have posted today if it had been posted 7 hours, 44 minutes, and 59 seconds later.

```
SELECT Posted_Date, Total_Payment FROM   
Table1
WHERE CAST(DATEADD(second,7*60*60+44*60+59,Posted_Date) AS date) = CAST(GETDATE() as date)
```

This will smoothly handle fencepost issues, fractional seconds, and daylight savings, and it will be very fast with an index on `CAST(DATEADD(second,7*60*60+44*60+59,Posted_Date) AS date)`

Comment: The problem with this is that it is non-sargable, making an index on the `Posted_Date` column either mostly or entirely useless.

Comment: Add an index, that doesn't even cover the query, on a non-persisted computed column to support an unnecessary non-sargable expression in a where clause? Sorry, that makes this suggestion worse, not better.

Comment: If your business logic defines the start of a time period differently from the standard calendar, sometimes it's better to index and partition your data according to *that* instead of forcing it into a different one.  If a business day starts and ends at 4:15PM, why not work with that?

Comment: ALTER TABLE Table1 ADD PostedBusinessDate AS CAST(DATEADD(second,7*60*60+44*60+59,Posted_Date) AS date); CREATE INDEX IX_PostedBusinessDate ON Table1(PostedBusinessDate) INCLUDE (Total_Payment)

Comment: Because maybe that's not a business day in all aspects of the business, or even all aspects of this table, just for this specific query. Never mind that the approach you're suggesting is downright confusing if you aren't looking at the table and this query at the same time.

Comment: Words fail me... For all of the reasons listed above this may be one of the worst pieces of advice I've seen in quite some time. I highly suggest you remove this answer on the off chance anyone mistakes it for advice.

Comment: It boils down to a date index for (date = @date) vs a datetime index for (datetime >= @start AND datetime < @end).  There exists a point where the performance is worth the additional complexity.

Comment: Great, can you *prove* that date = @date is going to be faster than an open-ended range query? And do you know that in this case you're not adding all that complexity just to satisfy *one* query, where currently you don't even know if performance is going to be an issue? And do you know that the additional overhead of maintaining that index for EVERY SINGLE DML EVENT ON THIS TABLE is justified?

Comment: In my experience, when I get asked for a report over specific time period, that is frequently followed by a request for a report over all similar time periods.  How would you approach grouping by time periods that span from 4:15PM to 4:15PM?

Comment: The way I did in my answer, without adding an additional index that requires maintenance over top of an index that may already exist on the base column. Stop trying to change their entire business process to satisfy one single query. The question here was about the logic for a WHERE clause, not how to completely re-engineer their entire schema.